# How to create a list with random integers

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create a random list of 1 million numbers ranging between 1-100. I have found how to create a single random number but not to create a list of them. In addition, I would prefer to use the numpy uniform function but the solution doesn't have to use this.

Comment: Look into [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why is there a numpy tag?

Comment: You might want to use a generator expression `(randint(1, 100) for i in range(1000000))` because I doubt you need to keep every random number in memory.

Answer (score 4):

For a big array, you'd better use numpy

```
 import numpy as np
 X = np.random.randint(1, 101, size=10**6)
```

Comment: The size should be a million, that is `10**6`

Answer (score 2):

Try this simpler one :

```
from random import randint

my_list = [randint(1, 100) for i in range(1000000)]
```

Comment: `random.sample(range(1,100), 1000000)` will also work!

Comment: @bro-grammer `range(1,101)`, but yes.

Comment: @chepner it is unclear from question whether 1-100 is inclusive or not.

Comment: @bro-grammer In what version? I get "ValueError: Sample larger than population"

Comment: @tobias_k yes indeed it won't work! I need to change it to list comprehension each with sample size of `99`. But then it won't be much different.

Comment: In regular English, "between 1-100" is an inclusive range. In any event, if you are suggesting an equivalent to something that uses `randint(1, 100)`, which *is* inclusive, you have to be inclusive as well.

Answer (score 0):

The function

```
np.random.rand(Dim1,Dim2)
```

will create an array for the given dimensions with values selected from the uniform distribution [0,1]. You can modify this to `randomArray = 1 + 99 * np.random.rand(Dim1,Dim2)` to have the array with numbers ranging between 1-100.

Comment: That's true, I guess the OP can use either 'rand' or 'randint'  depending on their choice of application.

Answer (score 0):

use this as simple as that...don't make your program more complex in code and in efficiency too..

```
from random import randint
l=[randint(1,100) for i in range(0,1000000)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  from random import *
  mylist = []
  for i in range(0, 100):
        f = randint(0, 100)
        mylist.insert(i, f)
```

This code will give 100 random elements to your empty list.

Comment: You need to move `mylist` initilization outside loop